# WebView and ViewPager, and Horizontal Scrollable Content

Tags: android, android-webview, android-viewpager

I have multiple `WebViews` showed in `ViewPager`, as pages, but i faced a problem if part of `WebView` content is `Horizontal Scrollable content`, I have tested it on iOS, and the `WebView` consume the `TouchEvent`, so the `ViewPager` doesn't scroll, but in android the `ViewPager` keeps scrolling, I tried to get the consume the `TouchEvent`, but I couldn't determine if the content is horizontal scrollable or not.

====
Edit 1:

the width of the content matches the webview, without scrollbars, but they put frame or i dont know what its name, the content inside it is horizontal scrollable. (Interactive Magazine)

- Little sample online http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/horizontal_scroll.cfm  (scroll down to result box)

Comment: I have not seen this behavior, having published an ebook in the form of `WebViews` in a `ViewPager`. In my experience, "it just works" -- the `WebView` scrolls first, then the `ViewPager` takes over once the `WebView` has reached the end in that direction. It may be that my content is simpler than yours, though, as I have only plain HTML and some images.

Comment: ill edit my question to be more clear. (btw i love your books, and your answers too)